# submit attachment using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to submit an attachment to a REST API. attachment is not submitted correctly. I believe that i'm doing something wrong with the request

```
RunQueryimage("http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Audi-A1.jpg);

public string RunQueryimage(string imagePath)
        {

            //do get request
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
                WebRequest.Create("https://iss.ontimenow.com/api/v2/incidents/");
            request.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            request.Method = "POST";

            var webClient = new WebClient();
            byte[] bytearr = webClient.DownloadData(imagePath);
            var filecontent = new ByteArrayContent(bytearr);
            // request.ContentLength = 0;

            if (filecontent != null)
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    writer.Write(filecontent);

                }
            }


            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)
                request.GetResponse();


            string result = string.Empty;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            return result;


        }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a stream open when you create a web request.

Change this:

```
byte[] bytearr = webClient.DownloadData(imagePath);    
var filecontent = new ByteArrayContent(bytearr);
        // request.ContentLength = 0;

        if (filecontent != null)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                writer.Write(filecontent);

            }
        }
```

To:

```
 byte[] fileContent = webClient.DownloadData(imagePath);

        if (fileContent != null)
        {
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
        }
```